# Android: Backup SQLite database using BackupAgentHelper not working at all

Tags: android, sqlite

I have gone through a lot of posts and read the documentation about 10 times. But still I am not able to backup my database using `FileBackupHelper`. I am using `BackupAgentHelper`.

**Please I need some help!!**

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="...">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:restoreAnyVersion="true"
    android:backupAgent=".MyBackupAgent"       
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.backup.api_key" android:value="..." />
</application>

</manifest>
```

MyBackupAgent.java

```
public class MyBackupAgent extends BackupAgentHelper {
    public void onCreate() {
        FileBackupHelper helper = new FileBackupHelper(this, this.getDatabasePath("mydb").getAbsolutePath());
        addHelper("db_file", helper);
        Log.d("Test", "Adding backup agent");  
    }
}
```

After that I run:

`adb shell bmgr run`

The logcat output is:

```
D/Test: Adding backupagent...
V/BackupServiceBinder: doBackup() invoked
D/BackupHelperDispatcher: handling existing helper 'db_file' android.app.backup.FileBackupHelper@425ab2f8
```

After that, I reinstall the app. But still the database is not restored.

Comment: what it the code for addHelper method

Comment: `addHelper()` is an inbuilt method of `BackupAgentHelper`, isnt it?

Comment: Did you find the root cause for the original issue?

I can not see any reason for not able to use Google's Backup Service for backup/restore of SQLite database file.

Regards, Amar

Comment: @amarnathpatel, I am using the 'Google Drive API' instead.